# ShellExecuteEx() in Windows 10 64 bit OS

Tags: c#, winapi

I am trying to execute notepad.exe from c# through ShellExecuteEx(). But notepad is not launching. I am running code in Windows 10 64 bit OS. Does this make any difference? What could be resolution.

Below is the code i have written

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO SEI = SHELLEXECUTEINFO.CreateInstance();
SEI.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(SEI);
SEI.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS | SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI 
          | SEE_MASK_NOASYNC | SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST;
SEI.hWnd = 0;
SEI.lpVerb = "open";
SEI.lpFile = sbResult.ToString(); //StringBuilder notepad.exe path 
SEI.lpParameters = sDocName; // txt file path
SEI.lpDirectory = "";
SEI.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
SEI.hInstApp = 0;
SEI.lpIDList = 0;
lReturnedCode = ShellExecuteEx(ref SEI);
WaitForSingleObject(SEI.hProcess, INFINITE);
```

Comment: Hard to say what is wrong given the lack of code. [Mcve] please.

Comment: If you just want to open a TXT file, you should provide just the TXT filename to `ShellExecute/Ex()` and let it figure out where the user's default text editor is located and how to run it: `SEI.lpFile = sDocName; SEI.lpParameters = "";` And don't blindly call `WaitForSingleObject()`, call it only if `ShellExecute/Ex()` returns success.

Comment: What does ShellExecuteEx return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to use `ShellExecuteEx()`. You can use [Process.Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Process proc = Process.Start("notepad.exe", sDocName);
```